# Calculating optical flow with opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am using the function:

```
cvCalcOpticalFlowBM
```

To calculate the optical flow.
The code is running, but the velocity matrices are zero (both x and y), although the input video clearly changes.
Does anyone have an idea why would the velocity matrices be zero (black)?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This tutorial shows how to use optical flow in opencv from scratch. It explains how to draw velocity vectors etc.

http://robots.stanford.edu/cs223b05/notes/CS%20223-B%20T1%20stavens_opencv_optical_flow.pdf